# How to turn off IntelliJ auto repo discovery VCS/Git

Tags: git, composer-php, jetbrains-ide

Using Composer patches I am getting added a lot of additional Git / VCS roots within my project sources. Somehow they all get registered as roots, are autofetched by gittoolbox (which already lead to getting added to a blacklist) and it lead to broken builds cause of conflicts at composer install recently.
I removed them from the registered roots by hand but this is really annoying.

[image]

**Can automatic VCS recognition be turned off while the main repo is still registered?**

The errors I get on build look like that (they are gone as soon as the repo folders are deleted and removed from the VSC table as  registered roots):

[image]

Or this:

```
Gathering patches for dependencies. This might take a minute.
  - Updating drupal/drupal_dam dev-1.0.x (f419cee => ceb5f6a):     Update failed (Source directory web/modules/contrib/drupal_dam has unpushed changes on the current branch
:
Branch 1.0.x could not be found on the origin remote and appears to be unpushed)
    Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]? yes
  - Removing drupal/drupal_dam (dev-1.0.x)

                                                                                                
  [RuntimeException]                                                                            
  Source directory web/modules/contrib/drupal_dam has unpushed changes on the current branch:   
  Branch 1.0.x could not be found on the origin remote and appears to be unpushed
```

Comment: Please share more details. How are these error messages related to any IDE?

Comment: The error messages seem to occur as soon as the IDE does Auto Fetch from those Repos and so on. Deleting the folders with repos inside and removig them from VCS table fixes the composer install. The question is how to avoid that the IDE starts adding found repos again. @NicoHaase

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Done already above: "The errors I get on build look like that (they are gone as soon as the repo folders are deleted and removed from the VSC table as registered roots):"